# how to get correct UUID of beacon from Corebluetooth framework api?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

i am developing an app to get uuid of beacon. i can also get uuid of beacon but it is wrong. formate is true but uuid is different. please help me. here is my code. first of all i get so many answer that is not possible from only core bluetooth api. you must have to on location service. i am trying to get uuid of beacon only core bluetooth api with location service off.

```
- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central
{
    switch (central.state)
    {
        case CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn:
        {
            NSDictionary *options = @{
                                      CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey: @YES
                                      };
            [manger scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil
                                             options:options];
            NSLog(@"I just started scanning for peripherals");
            break;
        }
    }
}
- (void)   centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central
    didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
        advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData
                     RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{
        strid = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[peripheral identifier]];
//D57092AC-DFAA-446C-8EF3-C81AA22815B5
    NSString *uuidString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, (__bridge CFUUIDRef)([[peripheral identifier] UUIDString]))];

}
- (IBAction)identifier:(UIButton *)sender {

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:strid delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
}
- (void)  centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central
    didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
{
    if (peripheral == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"connect callback has nil peripheral");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Connected to peripheral with identifer: %@, state: %d, name: %@, services: %@",
              [peripheral identifier],
              [peripheral state],
              [peripheral name],
              [peripheral services]);

        NSLog(@"discovering services...");
        peripheral = peripheral;
        peripheral.delegate = (id)self;
        [peripheral discoverServices:nil];
    }
}

- (void)     peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
    didDiscoverServices:(NSArray *)serviceUuids
{
    NSLog(@"discovered a peripheral's services: %@", serviceUuids);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Core Bluetooth only provides **peripheral UUID** which identifies a particular Bluetooth peripheral (beacon or not), and is generated by iOS when the device is first detected. It might differ between iOS devices, and might change after the device or Bluetooth is restarted.

The **iBeacon UUID** on the other hand comes from the advertising packet beacons broadcast, but Core Bluetooth filters out all data from iBeacon packets, so sadly, you can't learn it via Core Bluetooth.

I believe this was specifically done this way to prevent developers from using iBeacon without Location Services enabled or the appropriate permission granted. It's in the interest of the end-user: you likely wouldn't want apps to be able to access your GPS location without your explicit consent, and it's no different with the iBeacon. (Side-note: Google seems to agree, since in Android 6.0, they made it work the same way, i.e., you can't access beacon data without location permissions.)

Comment: thanx for response.. I can get specific peripheral  uuid of beacon so i can manually fix as a beacon id?.